# Menu at the end of the page but link from top to bottom

Tags: wordpress, menu

How can I achieve this? 
It's a wordpress menu.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caEru.png)

Ok, so far I have this:

```
ul{
    display: flex;

 li{
   width: 100%;

    a{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 2%;

     span{
      display: block;
      position:absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
         };
     };
   };
};
```

and it works, but now I need some kind of a javascript, so that the headings inside the span will be centered and every element will have the same amount of space from left and right.

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyVA2.jpg)

got it done, with adding left: %; to each menu item element.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If it is in `<a>` tag you can add padding to it so that the entire row will have the hand symbol and the link works when you keep the mouse anywhere from top to bottom..

Comment: Dont give height for the li tag you adjust the height size of the menu with the padding procedure and you will get it.

Comment: Post the live link i will make it up for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Made it like this: 
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uq3vLvpb/

The html:

```
<ul>

       <li><a><span>one</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>two</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>three</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>four</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>five</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>six</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>seven</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>eight</span></a></li>

    </ul>
```

The css:

```
ul {
    li {
      width: 100%;
      a {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 10.5%;
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        span {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          top: 65%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
          -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
          -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
        }
        &:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }
      }
    }

    li:first-child {
      a {
        left: 9.5%;
      }
    }

    li:nth-child(2) {
      a {
        left: 19.5%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      a {
        left: 29.6%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
      a {
        left: 39.6%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(5) {
      a {
        left: 49.7%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(6) {
      a {
        left: 59.8%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(7) {
      a {
        left: 69.9%;
      }
    }
    li:nth-child(8) {
      a {
        left: 80%;
       }
    }
  }
```